# Hello,Small probability related question

Tags: probability

We choose 4 random numbers from the set {0,1,....50}
with repetitions,
a. What is the probability that the sum of all the numbers is exactly 50?
b.What is the probability that the sum of all the numbers is exactly 50 AND all numbers are
equal or greater than 10.

for **a** my first move was to reduce to x1+x2+x3+x4=50 and then its (53C3)
then I divided by (50C4) , not sure Im right, please help on both counts.

Comment: The [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique will give you the number of permutations of numbers that add up to $50$.  You can then divide that by the number of ordered 4-tuples that can be drawn from $[0, 50]$.

Comment: Ahh, I see that it looks like you've done that.  If you want to check your answer, you may want to try the approach out on smaller numbers (where you can manually inspect the results).  I'm leaving my first comment for other readers who may want to know where you got the $\binom{53}{3}$ from.

Comment: In a) you have $51$ numbers so you need to divide by ${51 \choose 4}$

Comment: hint for b): you have four bins, each has $10$ objects. You have $10$ remaining objects that you need to distribute between the four bins. Now you can use the same approach that you used for a) (stars and bars).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\LARGE\left. a\right)}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{%
\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{50}{1 \over 51}\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{50}{1 \over 51}
\sum_{n_{3} = 0}^{50}{1 \over 51}\sum_{n_{4} = 0}^{50}{1 \over 51}
\bracks{n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} + n_{4} = 50}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{50}\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{50}
\sum_{n_{3} = 0}^{50}\sum_{n_{4} = 0}^{50}
\bracks{z^{50}}z^{n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} + n_{4}} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}
\pars{\sum_{n = 0}^{50}z^{n}}^{4}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}
\pars{z^{51} - 1 \over z - 1}^{4} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4}
\pars{1 - z^{51}}^{4}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}{-4 \choose 50} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}{53 \choose 50} =
{53 \times 52 \over 51^{3} \times 6}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{1378 \over 397953} \approx 0.00346272047201554
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\LARGE\left. b\right)}$ It's similar to the previous case but the $\ds{n}$-sum $\ds{\color{red}{starts}}$ at $\ds{n = 10}$.

Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{%
\sum_{n_{1} = 10}^{50}{1 \over 51}\sum_{n_{2} = 10}^{50}{1 \over 51}
\sum_{n_{3} = 10}^{50}{1 \over 51}\sum_{n_{4} = 10}^{50}{1 \over 51}
\bracks{n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} + n_{4} = 50}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}
\pars{\sum_{n = 10}^{50}z^{n}}^{4} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{50}}
\pars{z^{10}\,{z^{41} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{4}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{10}}
\pars{1 - z^{41} \over 1 - z}^{4} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} =
{1 \over 51^{4}}{-4 \choose 10}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 51^{4}}{13 \choose 10} =
\bbx{286 \over 6765201} \approx 0.0000422751666949733
\end{align}